# Is it possible to implement a function that can print any array of any type in C?

Tags: c, function, generics

I'm a newbie in C..  I was wondering that if I have three arrays like this:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3}
char b[] = {'a', 'c', 'k'}
float c[] = {4.5, 5.8}
```

Is it possible to write a polymorphic function that can print any one of these arrays like this?

```
prarray(a); prarray(b); prarray(c);
```

This form is also acceptable:

```
prarray(a, int); prarray(b, char); prarray(c, float)
```

Is it possible to work out the function `void prarray(void *)`? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: polymorphism in C !!!!!!!!!!!!!from when???

Comment: @perilbrain I know C doesn't have built-in polymorphism.. Is there some other methods to mimic polymorphism? like `void *`

Comment: C is a primitive language that is good for writing kernels or as an output language, but little else. If you want to do this, there are dozens of other languages in which it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do it without providing a lot of assistance to the called function so that it can do its job.  Look at the two 'polymorphic' functions in the standard C library, [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) and [`bsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bsearch.html).

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
       int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nel,
       size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The `printf()` and `scanf()` families are the other functions that handle multiple types.

Your print array function would likely need:

```
typedef int (*DataPrinter)(void *ctxt, void *data);
extern int prarray(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
                   DataPrinter pr_func, void *ctxt)
```

The data printer function pointer would be responsible for printing one value — specified by the `data` parameter.  The `ctxt` value is a pointer to whatever control information the data printer function needs (it might be as simple as a `FILE *`, it might be more complex).  The value returned from the data printer function is the number of characters written; the value returned from `prarray()` is the total number of characters written.

This only works for 1-dimensional arrays, of course.  For printing subsections of a 2D or 3D array, you need more complicated code.  If you need to worry about line breaks and the like, that is likely to be the domain of the `ctxt`.  Or you devise more complicated interfaces to this function.  Note that the only mechanism provided for specifying a value separator is via the `ctxt` structure.  This will work (or can be made to work), but it may be too clumsy.

---

The C2011 solution with `_Generic` is interesting, but requires N functions for N types, each of which handles printing an array.  I can't wriggle out completely: my solution requires N+1 functions, but only one of them (the 1) deals with arrays; the N functions each deal with printing a single value of a given type, which is a simpler process than printing the whole array of the given type.  Of course, as noted, it requires a C 2011 compiler on every platform of relevance.  Since at least one of the 'often relevant' platforms doesn't have a C 1999 compiler from its supplier, it may be a while before you can use C 2011 on that platform.

Answer (score 6):

The lastest C standard is C11 (C 2011).

It provides the keyword **_Generic** (§6.5.1.1 Generic selection, under section §6.5 Expressions) to do the kind of thing you ask for.

E.g.,

```
#define prarray(A, len) _Generic((A), \
    int: prarray_int, \
    char: prarray_char, \
    float: prarray_float, \
    )(A, len)

void prarray_int( int* a, ptrdiff_t len ) { ... }
void prarray_char( char* a, ptrdiff_t len ) { ... }
void prarray_float( float* a, ptrdiff_t len ) { ... }
```

Now all you need to do, is get hold of a C11 compiler! :-)

Or do the C11 macro's job, a little more manually - in practice, passing the name of the type as an explicit macro argument, and then use `##` token pasting to generate the function name.

Disclaimer: untested code (I have no C11 compiler), and also, I haven't used C since late 1990's.

Answer (score 2):

My second answer to the same question.

You can of course create a function that, if you pass it type information, it will know what to do with the data.  So, you could use a calling convention of:

```
prarray(a, len, 'i'); prarray(b, len, 'c'); prarray(c, len, 'f');
```

It would be better to use constants for 'i', 'c', and 'f', but you get the general idea.  The function definition would go something like this:

```
void parray(void *genericPtr, int len, char typeCode) {
    if (typeCode == 'i') {
        int *intArray = (int*) genericPtr;
        printIntArray(intArray, len);
    }
    if (typeCode == 'c') {
        char *charArray = (char*) genericPtr;
        printString(charArray, len);
    }
    if (typeCode == 'f') {
        float *floatArray = (float*) genericPtr;
        printFloatArray(floatArray, len);
    }
}
```

Note the evil, unsafe typecasting.

Comment: You're going to need to pass in a length.

Comment: Edited, thanks.  You know, probably the best example of polymorphic behavior in C that I've ever seen is in the OpenSSL library.

Answer (score 1):

the closest you can get without a C11 compiler is probably a macro

```
#define prarray(array, format, length) ({\
    size_t i;\
    size_t _length = length ;
    for (i = 0; i < _length; i++) \
        printf(format ",", (array)[i]);\
})\
```

invoke with format as your printf format string. e.g. `"%c"` for character, `"%d"` for `int` etc...

Answer (score 0):

In c there is no polymorphism.  To do this without unsafe practices, there have to be three different funcitons which are passed the array and its length. ie;  void print_ints(int *a,int size); and so on.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Would you care to give a hint about what features in C11 you are thinking of as being applicable to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

The longer answer is that you can create a new data type that can contain different kinds of values, then write a function which knows how to print them out.  That would give you what you want, but defining your values can be syntactically awkward.

Frankly, it is exactly this kind of problem which encouraged people to invent dynamic languages, OOP, etc..

My C is really rusty, but...

```
struct varyThing {
    char typeCode; // indicates what type of data it is.
    union valueUnion {
        long longValue;
        float floatValue;
        char string[32];
    } value;
};
```

The whole structure only takes up maybe 34 bytes, depending on type sizes and byte alignments and other compiler details.